How to specify target architecture when using Spring Boot gradle task bootBuildImage
I'm trying to build an ARM image on an amd64 node.
This documentation about buildpacks states that I can do it using heroku/builder:24 as the builder image and passing the platform as a parameter --platform linux/arm64
I'm using bootBuildImage gradle task to build my image. I learned how to specify a builder image like:

bootBuildImage {
    archiveFile = war.archiveFile
    if (System.getenv('CI')) {
        builder = "heroku/builder:24"
//...

But I couldn't find any way to pass the platform. Isn't this impossible using the gradle task? Should I revert to building my images using Dockerfiles or using buildpack commands directly?

For the time being you need to use the pack cli to build and specify the platform. This is a newer argument, and I don't believe Spring Boot Build Tools support it yet.

Setting the platform will tell the tooling to pick images of the given architecture. It is not magic though, you still need hardware to support running those images. It works nicely on Apple M-series hardware which can easily run both amd64 & arm64, otherwise, you would need to run that build inside of QEMU or something similar to have it properly built. You can have Github Actions do that, see https://github.com/paketo-buildpacks/native-image/issues/338#issuecomment-2366841227 for an example.

I have an environment with QEMU installed and I can succesfully build docker images for both platforms on it, using regular Dockerfiles. But I couldn't find a way to pass the platform argument using spring's task.

The future release of Spring Boot, 3.4.0, will provide you with the option to choose the target platform
https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/3.4-SNAPSHOT/gradle-plugin/packaging-oci-image.html#build-image.customization
bootBuildImage {
    imagePlatform = "linux/arm64"
    [etc]

Like @Daniel Mikusa  suggested in the comments, you will need a host that can provide an ARM 64 capability; such as Mac Silicons or probably Linux hosts with arm64 emulation enabled and configured in the Docker Daemon

Thanks, so there is no way to do it yet. I already have a host setup with QEMU which I use to build images for both platforms when I use plain Dockerfiles insteaed of bootBuildImage

well, you could also use the milestone releases; in https://start.spring.io/ 3.4.0.M3 is out, and RC1 October 24th, https://calendar.spring.io/

You can also use the pack cli, which builds with the same set of buildpacks. It's just a different interface. https://buildpacks.io/docs/for-platform-operators/how-to/integrate-ci/pack/
